# Arduino Text to Speech

Tags: arduino, speech

has anyone used the arduino to convert text to speech?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cantarino](http://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/Cantarino) is a work in progress software speech synthesizer for Arduino. You could also interface with several [speech synth chips](http://www.speechchips.com/shop/) available. Devantech [SP03](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/Sp03doc.shtml) module has been popular but it is hard to find. What makes it especially cool is the I2C interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible to use the PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) to playback audio samples - but at very low quality. I've heard this done on the BBC Micro game [Exile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exile%5F%28arcade%5Fadventure%29), on a 6502 CPU way back in the day. Text to speech seems like quite a lot to ask of an ATMEGA series chip. But who knows what clever people are out there to prove me wrong!

Answer (score 1):

[speechchips.com](http://www.speechchips.com/shop/) sells a few IC's programmed to handle text-to-speech for you.

Depending on your application though...you can probably get much better quality simply using pre-recorded audio stored on a SD card or something. Sure it might take a couple hundred MB for all your different speech recordings, but that's just pennies at today's SD card prices, and SD cards can be interfaced via SPI.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered this blog post on LMR. Looks pretty cool.
[SpeakJet](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/11969)